# Toggling between remote KGDB and local DDB within a debugging session

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging, freebsd, kgdb

I would like to know if there is indeed a way to toggle between gdb and ddb while debugging a remote kernel.

I am already at the gdb (or rather kgdb) prompt. From here how do I switch to local ddb on the debugged machine?

My kernel configuration file already contains `options BREAK_TO_DEBUGGER` and I have BOTH GDB and DDB configured aka:

```
options GDB
options DDB
```

As per the [developer's handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug-online-gdb.html), "Every time you type gdb, the mode will be toggled between remote GDB and local DDB. In order to force a next trap immediately, simply type s (step). Your hosting GDB will now gain control over the target kernel:"

So, I did try typing 'gdb' at the gdb prompt (funny me:D) and as expected, it was an unrecognized command. Obviously, this command is supposed to be typed at the ddb prompt. But my question is, how do I drop to ddb from within a running machine whose serial ports (albeit virtual ones) are remotely attached to another machine's KGDB? When remote GDB is listening and I force a panic using `sysctl debug.kdb.enter=1`, it does drop into remote KGDB. However, when it is NOT listening, the system just freezes.

What I want, is to enter ddb on the local machine. Do some debugging using it; drop to remote KGDB for things that are best done using KGDB, then switch back to local DDB when I'm done.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

KDB contains DDB & KDB backends, but there are a lot of conditions when they are available. To check if backend is available, check sysctl debug.kdb.available and debug.kdb.current (sys/kern/subr_kdb.c). If both backends are available, debug.kdb.available should contains "ddb gdb".

The possible way to toggle between backends (gdb / ddb) is to enter ddb at first, then call gdb and make debugging. Then exit gdb, and return to ddb (actually new trap will happen, seems Ctrl+C is required). It means that before panic, debug.kdb.current should be set to "ddb".

I hope it will help.

Comment: `sysctl debug.kdb.available` gives `ddb gdb`

`sysctl debug.kdb.current` gives `gdb`

I've tried ctrl-c at the ddb prompt (when gdb was active) to return control back to GDB but to no avail.

if I play around with `debug.kdb.current` can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Not sure. there should be 1 backend in time. Transition from DDB to GDB is "gdb" command, transition back is to terminate gdb.

Comment: I changed the current backend to ddb with `sysctl debug.kdb.current=ddb`. Then I triggered a panic and I was at the ddb prompt. Typing `gdb` here connects the machine to the gdb backend on the client machine. 

However quitting gdb there takes me back to the shell prompt on the debugged machine and NOT to ddb. Is this how it should be?